# Next.js - Broken listeners after static export

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4, next.js

I tried this approach:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'

    export default class AlertHey extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
        }

        handleClick(){
            alert("hey")
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Click me
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

And this approach:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

    export default class AlertHey extends Component {

        render(){
            return(
                <div onClick={() => alert("Hey")}>
                    Click me
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

And both don't work. In develpment mode (npm run dev) all works well, while when I export, all listeners seems broken. I don't get it. Maybe I lost any babel or webpack setting?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in production? I noticed you don't have a return () tags in your render method. You also have to bind this.handleClick to your instance rather than handleClick1.

Comment: Yes, it works. Missing return and handleclick1 are typos